# how to get the id of the clicked item

Tags: meteor

i need to get the id of the currently clicked item .
i've done dirty solution for now , i store the id of the current item , in the button's id ,the retrieve the id on click on that button in the template manager.

```
<button type="button" id ="{{id}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>View</button>
```

then in the manager i do .

```
    Template.formItem.events = {

  "click .btn":function (e){
    Router.go('forms.show', {_id: $(e.target).attr('id')}, {query: 'q=s', hash: 'hashFrag'});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

if the data context has id then,`this.id` will work

Try consoling this `console.log(this)` on click event

```
 "click .btn":function (e){
    console.log(this);
    Router.go('forms.show', {_id: this.id}, {query: 'q=s', hash: 'hashFrag'});
  }
```

**EDIT**

Also, read this article https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes

This is one of the common mistakes author mentioned in that post.

Comment: This is not correct, this refers to the template object, not the button element.

Comment: @SandervandenAkker, No, the second parameter in the event handler refers to the template instance. `this` refers to the data context used to render the element catching the event.

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry. Then both answers will work.

Answer (score 3):

To get to the element that is clicked in a Meteor template click event, use the currentTarget property:

```
"click .btn":function (event) {
  Router.go('forms.show', {_id: event.currentTarget.id}, {query: 'q=s', hash: 'hashFrag'});
}
```

This is also valid for other events like submit, mouseover etc.